# Where does VSC get its information that's displayed in the tooltips?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

When I hover over a method, VSC displays information on that method in a tooltip.

**Example:** Here, I hover over `.on`, a method I'm using from the Socket IO library. Then I can see documentation on `.on`:

[image]

**Question:** Where does VSC grab documentation from to display in the tooltips?

I couldn't find any of this info in the socket.io package, or any other respective package for different libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks to come from [@types/socket.io](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/631d6af27fb1ef85d1d6e92bfb3acccc4d744640/types/socket.io/index.d.ts#L211), which is part of [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) - the defacto repo for all TypeScript community-maintained type definitions.

> VS Code provides IntelliSense for built-in symbols of browsers, Node.js, and virtually all other environments through the use of type definition `.d.ts` files. DefinitelyTyped is a repository of typings files for all major JavaScript libraries and environments. — [vscode.readthedocs.io](https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/stable/languages/javascript/#intellisense-support)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's from the docstring you can put inside at the top of a function